# Am I violating the data modelling rule in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

I understand that we should not create 'N' number of partition under a single table because in this case, it tries to query from N number of nodes where the partitions are available.

(Modifying the example for understanding and security)

If I have a table like 'user'

```
CREATE TABLE user(
   user_id int PRIMARY KEY,
   user_name text,
   user_phone varint
   );
```

where user_id is unique.

Example - To get all the users from the table, I use the query :

```
select * from user;
```

So which means It goes to all the nodes where the partitions for the 'user_id' are available. Since I used the user_id as partition / primary key here, It will be scattered to all the nodes based on the partition_id.

Is it fine? Or Is there a better way to design this in Cassandra?

**Edited :**

By Keeping a single partition as 'uniquekey' and sorted by user_name will have the advantage that uniquekey will make a single partition. Is it the better design compare to the above one?

```
CREATE TABLE user(
   user_id int,
   user_name text,
   user_phone varint,
   primary key ('uniquekey', user_name));



select * from user where user_id = 'uniquekey';
```

Comment: Distributed databases like Cassandra aim for scaling horizontally and hence require partition key based queries.  It isn't designed to serve "select * " type of queries. Also the alternate datamodel provided above is worse as the entire data would end up in a single node. So not recommended.

Comment: @dilsingi Why do you think its worse? If I have 1000 entries in a partition then which approach is better, Reading from a single partition from one node (or) going to multiple node for multiple partition and fetch the data?

Comment: There are bucketing strategies to split the partition not to have 1000 entries altogether. The recommendation is to keep a partition size < 100MB (though theoretically one could store a lot more). Just curious, why would an app need all 1000 entries to be served out (a.k.a "select *")?

Comment: @dilsingi, My app need to retrieve all the entries from a table. Before that It would be Great If you could tell me "Reading from a single partition from one node (or) going to multiple node for multiple partition and fetch the data?" which is better If I have 1000 entries? In my case, I will have user_id as 'primary / partition key', which means I will have 1000 partitions so How will you design this better is my question.

Comment: Cassandra isn't your best choice, having to retrieve all.

Comment: Also for sure, number of entries in this table won't cross 1000 entries and data size will be lesser than 10 MB

Comment: Can you answer this question please : "Reading from a single partition from one node (or) going to multiple node for multiple partition and fetch the data?" which is better If I have 1000 entries?

Comment: The short answer, is "yes you are violating modeling rules with Cassandra."  Postgres is probably a much better fit for this.

Comment: @Aaron, can you tell me why ? ]

Comment: Having to employ extra engineering to do something simple, is a good indication that you are using the wrong data store.  Also, using a "constant" partition key creates hotspots in your cluster.

Comment: @Aaron, I explored the Cassandra completely, If I will have only 1000 entries with constant partition why it is gonna create the Hotspot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fundamental table design rule in Cassandra is called **Query-Driven**, which means you usually understand what are you trying to query on before you make the table schema.

If you just want to simply return all the rows (select * ) in the database (which is not a common use case for Cassandra since Cassandra aims to store very, very large amount of data), whatever you designed is fine. But Cassandra might not be the best choice in this case.

How to ensure a good table design in Cassandra?
Ref: [Basic Rules of Cassandra Data Modeling](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)

Comment: Thanks, Before accepting your answer which of my two design is suited? My app needs to retrieve all the entries from a table. Also, tell me "Reading from a single partition from one node (or) going to multiple node for multiple partition and fetch the data?" which is better If I have 1000 entries? In my case, I will have user_id as 'primary / partition key', which means I will have 1000 partitions? Or second design with constant partition key is fine?

Comment: @Harry okay, think of this question: this is an app and currently has 1000 users. What if the amount of users grows in the future? If you go with Design 2, you will always have one constant partition and the partition goes larger and larger. It violates the design concepts of Cassandra. I think you are worrying about too many small partitions will have an effect on the performance, i think its not an issue based on your current data amount.

Comment: I am very sure that the total entries in the table will never be crossing 10K, so It is good to have single partition (or) have multiple small partitions is my question.

Comment: @Harry then you can go with the single partition since what you try to do is to select all users. But if you want to query on specific username, go with small partitions.

Comment: Thanks, @Ev3rlasting Also, I would like to highlight that, there will be a frequent update in the column values, In this case which is a recommended design?

Comment: @Harry The role of `clustering key` is for sorting inside a partition. If you want to frequent update a column value (eg, user_phone), I would suggest you choose the design of different partitions.

Comment: Agree, but this makes the read complex right? select * from users; without a partition key?